# Forward a non-standard port using iptables

Tags: debian, iptables, port-forwarding

i'm having problem forwarding a port (for example: 50001) to another PC (192.168.1.101). The port 50001 is used to Remote Desktop (The client PC is listening on this port for the new connections).

The server is a Debian with an external interface (eth0) and a internal interface (eth2).

```
EXTIF="eth0"
INTIF="eth2"

iptables-restore <<-EOF
*nat
-A POSTROUTING -o "$EXTIF" -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A FORWARD -i "$EXTIF" -o "$INTIF" -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i "$INTIF" -o "$EXTIF" -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -j LOG
COMMIT
EOF


iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -i $EXTIF --dport 3389 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.100:3389
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -d 192.168.1.100 --dport 3389 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -i $EXTIF --dport 1433 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.100:1433
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -d 192.168.1.100 --dport 1433 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -i $EXTIF --dport 2470 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.100:2470
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -d 192.168.1.100 --dport 2470 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -i $EXTIF --dport 50001 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.101:50001
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -d 192.168.1.101 --dport 50001 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

Now... the forwarding of ports 3389, 1433 and 2470 works fine. But 50001 doesn't work.

i've already tested changing the FORWARD's policy to ACCEPT and nothing change.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Desktop_Protocol seems to suggest that RDP uses UDP as well as TCP, but I see no rules for handling the forwarding of UDP. Have you tried adding this?

Comment: Yes, i've tried, and doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you haven't changed the port the RDP is listening to on the internal server so change the lines

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -i $EXTIF --dport 50001 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.101:50001
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -d 192.168.1.101 --dport 50001 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

to

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -i $EXTIF --dport 50001 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.101:3389
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -d 192.168.1.101 --dport 3389 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: The PC Client is listening on port 50001.

Comment: Can you confirm that the port on the server is open (telnet 192.168.1.101 50001) from the firewall

Comment: From the LAN: telnet 192.168.1.101 50001  Trying 192.168.1.101...
Connected to 192.168.1.101.

Comment: Next confirm that the firewall on 192.168.1.101 is accepting connections from outside the LAN, I would normally do this with a tcpdump on the firewall. Something like: tcpdump -i eth2 -nn port 50001 and host 192.168.1.101